# I want to have different fonts for each language. (SCSS)

Tags: css, sass, fonts, hugo

I want to have different fonts for each language.

But this doesn't work.(hugo 0.90.2)

What's wrong?

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Noto Sans KR';
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans+KR:wght@300;400;500;700;900&display=swap');
  unicode-range: U+AC00-D7A3, U+0030-0039;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;700&display=swap');
  unicode-range: U+0041-005A, U+0061-007A;
}

:root {
  --font-family-heading: 'Poppins', 'Noto Sans KR', sans-serif;
  --font-family-paragraph: Helvetica, 'Noto Sans KR', sans-serif;
  --font-family-mono: monospace, 'Noto Sans KR';
  --base-color: #ffffff;
  --base-offset-color: #eaeaea;
  --highlight-color: #7b16ff;
  --heading-color: #1c1b1d;
  --text-color: #4e5157;
}
```

my site
https://ravenearth.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined css font family variables not properly.
You should provide **prioritized** list of one or more font family names. First going to be most prioritized font family name, if it will be missing - browser will take next font family name from list, and so on.

```css
:root {
  --font-family-heading: 'Poppins', 'Noto Sans KR', sans-serif;
  --font-family-paragraph: 'Noto Sans KR', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  --font-family-mono: 'Noto Sans KR', monospace;
  ...
}
```

To override root variables in accordance to selected language, you can use ":lang()" selector:

```scss
// Korean language
html:lang(ko):root {
    --font-family-h1: sans-serif;
}

// English language
html:lang(en):root {
    --font-family-h1: monospace;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `:lang` selector for this. An example of this could be:

```
/* Selects any <p> in English (en) */
p:lang(en) {

}
```